# First-Move Advantage

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

Here's a quick one. The final answer is a 6-letter word.

---

*First player advantage? I don't believe in anything like that. It's just an excuse people use to explain away why they lost. Instead, victory solely depends on which side gets the* next *move.*

[image: 8-by-8 grid of letters, backgrounds shaded three ways; more detail given below]

Text version is below: the first grid is the letters of the board, and the second is the shading. `#` is the darkest, followed by `X`, and then `.` is the lightest.

```
BASTILLE XXXXXXX#  
ECHIDNAS XXXXXXXX  
POTBOUND XXXXXXXX  
KEPHALIC XX..XX..  
TELETYPE XX..XX..  
NEWSWEEK ........  
CABOMBAS ........  
ALTRUISM #.......
```

Hint 1:

> At least 32 letters in the grid are just disguising the true information.

Comment: The text version doesn't capture the shading of the squares. Is it worth adding to the question a description of how the board is shaded, for the benefit of anyone who for whatever reason can't view images?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, very much so, yes. Not every computer can pull images from imgur. Better yet, stick that in the image description where it goes.

Comment: My question was addressed more to the OP -- it may turn out that the shading is purely decorative. But I'll add some explanation to the question.

Comment: I can try putting the grid in markdown if that would help.

Comment: Maybe provide a hunt now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potential answer:

> Beings

Solution:

> This is a chessboard. Pieces are denoted by their usual letters from [algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)) - King, kNight, Bishop, Rook - plus P for pawn; ignore other letters for now. Pieces on darker/lighter squares are black/white. Just as we're told, "victory solely depends on which side gets the next move": white/black can checkmate with Be1/Ng5. Treating the 1 and 5 in Be1Ng5 as the similar-looking letters I and S, we have the 6-letter answer "Beings" (thanks ffao for pointing this out!). However if this is the entire solution, then the two extra-dark squares are red herrings??

Comment: "beings"? that is a six-letter word.

Comment: Oh wow, that was staring me in the face! Thanks, I've updated the answer. Though I'm a little concerned there's one part of the puzzle we never used...

Comment: Board with appropriate pieces on lichess [here](https://lichess.org/editor/b7/5n2/p2b2n1/k1P5/6P1/N6K/2B2B2/3R4_w_KQkq_-) in case you want to put that, or an image derived from it, into your answer.

Comment: Perhaps the extra-dark squares are meant to hint at the board being a chessboard (with dark squares in those corners and light squares in the other two corners)?

Comment: (The first version of the puzzle had extra-light squares in the other two corners.)

Comment: It was a hint that it is a chessboard. The original plan was to clue the words and have the board created via that (thus the long words), but that proved too complicated for solvers (plus being a letter off would make the double mate not work. After I posted this, I realized I could make the same puzzle with some black squares and make a crossword chessboard, but that's for a later time (and once I find a better Be1/Ng5 double mate that could be placed on a board where the bottom half is white instead of the puzzle piece delimitation it is now)